# Storing data in local storage when component mounts

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to store a randomly generated user id in local storage on my React application when the component mounts. I first perform a check to see if the random id exists. Its supposed to be created only if it does not exist.
The problem I am facing is that the Id is created twice in local storage. I only want it to be created once. Here is my code.

```
   function App() {
React.useEffect(()=>{
    generateRandomUserId()
  },[])
      const generateRandomUserId = () => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('randId')) {
          localStorage.setItem('randId', uuid())
        }
      }
```

Comment: How are you validating/verifying that an id is created twice?

Comment: When i check local storage the randid item appears twice with two different Ids

Comment: You see the same key twice in local storage?? Should just overwrite the value.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce using your code copy/pasted into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/storing-data-in-local-storage-when-component-mounts-01iuu). I see only 1 value written to localStorage. Are you sure what is happening?

Comment: But both look different, randId and randid. The I is lowercase in one of them

Comment: Where are you writing a `randid` key to localStorage? Have you not included all relevant code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you sure you didn't just accidentally write once with `randid` when testing? Delete both and rerun your code and see what is written.